# Excel Formula: How to loop through an array and check if part of another list

Tags: arrays, excel, excel-formula, formula

I am wondering if it is possible - using an Excel formula (no vba) - to loop through a list with values and check if those values are in another list. The idea is to use this to come up with a sum pulling data from the first list while the second list sets the conditions. Please see below picture. I was thinking that this might work with sumproduct including an if-statement. Any ideas?

[image: example_visualized]

Comment: Is the result to be the corresponding sum of `Tabelle2[amount]`, or the count of `Tabelle2[item]`? i.e., `11`, or `3`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work (F1):

```
=SUM(SUMIF(Table1[Item],Table2[Included],Table1[Amount]))
```

but you may need to array-enter it or use SUMPRODUCT instead of SUM in pre-365 versions of Excel.

[image]

If you wanted to match ? literally rather than as a wild card standing for any single character you would need F2:

```
=SUM(SUMIF(Table1[Item],SUBSTITUTE(Table2[Included],"?","~?"),Table1[Amount]))
```

and similarly for *.